# Oracle PSQL getting reason of error in a with as expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a more thousand lines "with as" sql. When I try to run it I've got a message:
"Expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression", but I cannot get any info where is it and which field is not the same type. In a normal sql I can get it, but in with as I cannot. Yes I know "with as" is not the best practice, but I have to port an old sql to a new environment.

Is there any trick to get where is it?

Comment: so take that same with and run it as a sql..then you'll know...also, examples here help us help YOU a lot

Comment: Take a binary division approach.  Try it once with the first 500 lines, and then with the second 500. Then cut the failing section in half again and test to find the failing group. This will quickly isolate the offending element.

Comment: One possible source would be any set operators (union, intersect, etc).  All of them at the same level, must have the same number  and data type in the expression.

Comment: yes I made a binary division, and I find a 10 encapsulated sql. But it is absolutely stupid thing plsql find an error but doesn't say it. I waste my time to find it. Oracle is not my favorite.